# Move marker with mouse in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to move marker with mouse move event on google maps.

Following is my code to add marker on google maps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Simple markers</title>
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
 var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 4,
  center: myLatlng
 }
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
 });
 }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
```

This is a simple marker example taken from     https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

On mouse move i want to move marker with mouse. But i dont know how to do it

Comment: are you sure is not making the marker draggable what you want? var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!',
  draggalbe: true
 });

Answer (score 4):

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: map.getCenter(),
                map: map,
                title: 'Click to zoom'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(e) {
                marker.setPosition(e.latLng);
            });
```

Using this code we can move marker with mouse on google maps

Comment: `google.maps.Marker.setPosition` has this signature: `setPosition(latlng:LatLng)`. It does not take mas as parameter. In your example map will be ignored!

Comment: So, you answered your own question? Is this what you really want? May I know in which application do you want this? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: It's [perfectly acceptable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to ask a question then answer it yourself

Answer (score 2):

If I understant you want to be able to move the marker with the mouse. Not necessarily to move it at the `mousemouve` event. To be able to do this all you have to do is set the `draggable` property of the marker to `true`.

Consider the following exemple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Simple markers</title>
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
 var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 4,
  center: myLatlng
 }
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!',
  draggable: true
 });
 }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
```

To refer to all properties the marker have read: [MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions)

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) for event listeners in google maps

Comment: it does not have mouse move event